# jqGrid ASP.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I am able to display my records on jqGrid however the paging is not working. I have 90 records in total and its always showing the first 10 records even though the page number did increase. I had checked the return values to jqGrid from my method and it did show a different set of records being sent to jqGrid but jqGrid is not able to display that new set of records.

Below is my code.

```
public JsonResult CheckReading(int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord)
{
    IList<SamplerReading> Model =
                             (IList<SamplerReading>)Session["samplerReadingArray"];
    int totalRecords = Model.Count + 1;
    int pageSize = rows;
    int pageIndex = Convert.ToInt32(page) - 1;
    int totalPages = (int)Math.Ceiling((float)totalRecords / (float)pageSize);

    string orderBy = string.Format("{0} {1}", sidx, sord);

    var sales = Model.AsQueryable()
            .OrderBy(orderBy) // Uses System.Linq.Dynamic library for sorting
            .Skip(pageIndex * pageSize)
            .Take(pageSize);

    var jsonData = new
    {
        total = totalPages,
        page = page,
        records = totalRecords,
        rows = (
              from s in Model
              select new
              {
                  i = s.ReadingId,
                  cell = new string[] {
                      s.SamplingDate.ToShortDateString(),
                      s.Ph.ToString(),
                      s.Ec.ToString(),
                      s.Arsenic.ToString(),
                      s.Temperature.ToString(), 
                      s.OilAndGrease.ToString(),
                      s.DepthToCollar.ToString()
                  }
              }).ToArray()
    };
    return Json(jsonData);
}
```

where

```
   <table id="list" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
   </table>
   <div id="pager" style="text-align: center;">
   </div>
```

and

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var gridimgpath = '/Scripts/jqgrid/themes/redmond/images';
   var gridDataUrl = '/Shared/CheckReading';
   jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
       url: gridDataUrl,
       datatype: "json",
       mtype: 'GET',
       colNames: ['Sampling Date', 'pH', 'EC', 'Arsenic', 'Temperature',
                  'Oil and Grease', 'Depth to Collar'],
       colModel: [
           { name: 'SamplingDate', index: 'SamplingDate', width: 100, align: 'left'},
           { name: 'Ph', index: 'Ph', width: 30, align: 'left' },
           { name: 'Ec', index: 'EC', width: 30, align: 'left' },
           { name: 'Arsenic', index: 'Arsenic', width: 30, align: 'left' },
           { name: 'Temperature', index: 'Temperature', width: 30, align: 'left' },
           { name: 'Oil And Grease', index: 'OilAndGrease', width: 30, align:'left'},
           { name: 'Depth To Collar', index: 'DepthToCollar', width:30,align:'right'}
       ],
       rowNum: 10,
       rowList: [10, 20, 30],
       imgpath: gridimgpath,
       height: 'auto',
       width: '900',
       pager: jQuery('#pager'),
       sortname: 'ReadingId',
       viewrecords: true,
       sortorder: "desc",
       caption: "Sampler Readings",
       edit: true
    }).navGrid("#pager", { edit: true, add: false, del: false }); 
</script>
```

Comment: Are there any JavaScript errors?

Answer (score 1):

You code seems to me your code has some small errors. The most important which I see is that you should place all JavaScript code inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {/* your code */});` handle.

1. The `total` or `totalRecords` should be equal to `Model.Count` and not `Model.Count + 1`.
2. The usage of `Convert.ToInt32(page)` is not needed. You can just use `page` direct.
3. You can calculate `total` or `totalPages` without usage of some float arithmetic: `totalPages = (totalRecords + rows - 1) / rows`. This will make the same rounding.
4. You should returns rows having `id` and not `i`. So you should replace `i = s.ReadingId` to `id = s.ReadingId`
5. The usage of `sidx` and `sord` directly without any checking I find dangerous. In the way you can allow SQL Injection. It is very easy to replace `sord` with for example

   String.Compare (sord, "desc", StringComparison.Ordinal) == 0 ? "desc": "asc"

then you can be sure that you will use no hacks inside of `sord`. In the same way you can verify `sidx` as a property of `SamplerReading`. It seems to me that you can use .NET Reflection: `typeof(SamplerReading).GetProperties()`. Instead of this you can also verify that `sidx` is in the list (array) of following strings `'SamplingDate','Ph','EC','Arsenic','Temperature','OilAndGrease','DepthToCollar'` and use no other value of `sidx`.

1. You should place all JavaScript code inside of `jQuery(document).ready(function() {/* your code */});` handle.
2. From the jqGrid definition you could remove deprecated `imgpath` parameter and default property `align: 'left'` from the every column definition. There are also no parameter `edit: true` in jqGrid.
3. The HTML markup

can be reduce to

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

You don't wrote which version of ASP.NET MVC you use. Probably 1.0 version. For MVC 2.0 you should use `Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet)`.

I recommend you verify in [Fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/2.) of Firebug what will be send in the requests to the server and what will be send back. Moreover ids of all `<tr>` elements of the table must be the values of `ReadingId` which you send back. Verify also by setting breakpoints in the `CheckReading` function that the client get the response every time from the server and not from the local cache.

Comment: You can simply the ready function to `$(function() { /* your code */ });`, although I don't believe you actually need to use it in this case. In fact there are a lot of times you don't actually need to use the ready function.

Comment: @Ryan: Of cause `$(function()` is the same as `jQuery(document).ready(function()`, but if somebody forget to use this I recommend always the `ready` version which shows better what it do: it wait for document DOM tree has been **fully loaded**/constructed (not a full windows with all images and videos). Because jqGrid create the grid almost only with respect of DOM manipulation it is required. I am not sure that this change along will fix the problem, but it is nevertheless really needed.

Comment: Hey thanks for the reply. I found out where the error is already. It seems that I did not point to the correct collections. It should be pointing to "sales" rather than Model in the jsonData section.